# Can I use different colors based on the monotonicity of the values in a Highstock chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have a [basic line graph](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line). I want this line to be green when the values are increasing (i.e., current>previous) and red when they are decreasing. Is it possible?

I am aware of this workaround: instead of the original values, I will show the difference between current value and the previous value. This way, if in the new graph I have something greater than 0, it means the original graph is ascending. And I am able to show [different colors based on a threshold](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/4030687-have-multiple-thresholds-on-the-graph-so-you-can-h) (so, in the new graph, when value>0, I will use green, and I will know that part of the graph corresponds to an increasing area in the original graph). I am interested in a resolution for the original problem, though.

Comment: What about using https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Comment: You can preprocess your data, before creating a chart. Loop over all points, compare with previous (if exists) point value and set `color` for a point. That will change marker color. And if you want to change line color, use [Multicolor Series plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/33/Multicolor%20series).

Comment: Thanks you both. Paweł, I will implement your suggestion.